# How to use mapmode-x (xmap) and mapmode-s (smap) in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, key-bindings

I have these two key mappings to surround the visual selection with double asterisks:

```
" This one works for line selections done with V, but not selections done with v
vmap <A-b> <ESC>'<I**<ESC>'>A**<ESC>gv
```

```
" This one works for selections done with v, but not selections done with V
vmap <A-b> o<ESC>i**<ESC>gvO<ESC>2la**<ESC>gv4l
```

They both work, so I'd like to make it so that they only execute in visual line (V) and visual select (v), exclusively.

According to the documentation for `mapmode-x` and `mapmode-s`, there is a way to create mappings exclusive to visual line and visual select:

```
    COMMANDS                                  MODES  
                                          Visual    Select  
:vmap  :vnoremap  :vunmap  :vmapclear       yes      yes
:xmap  :xnoremap  :xunmap  :xmapclear       yes       -
:smap  :snoremap  :sunmap  :smapclear       -        yes
```

However, when I map either of them to `smap`, when I select some text with `v` and press `<A-b>`, nothing happens.

- e.g., `smap <A-b> o<ESC>i**<ESC>gvO<ESC>2la**<ESC>gv4l`

When I map either of them to `xmap` and make a selection with `v` or `V`, `<A-b>` will executes regardless.

- e.g., `xmap <A-b> o<ESC>i**<ESC>gvO<ESC>2la**<ESC>gv4l`

(I tested `smap` and `xmap` individually with `--clean`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `xmap` and `smap` is that:

- The first (`xmap`) applies in Visual mode and
- The second (`smap`) applies in Select mode.

The difference between Visual mode and Select mode is not that the first is triggered with `V` and the second with `v`.

## Select Mode

The Select mode has been introduced to have a mode similar to the select mode of other text editors: You select a part of the text and when you type some text the selection is replaced by the typed text.

The Select mode is somehow similar to Visual mode. Like in Visual mode there are tree sub Select modes:

- Line wise that you can start with `gH`
- Character wise that you can start with `gh`
- Block wise that that you can start with `g`<kbd>Ctrl h</kbd>

Remark: Select mode is different from Visual mode in the sense that:

- The selection can only by changed using motion keys (i.e. <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and their <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> combinations).
- If you type any printable key the selection will be replaced by the typed text (e.g.: `h`, `j`, `k`, `l`, `gg`, ...)

There is an alternative way way to enter in select mode that depends of the `selectmode` option:

If `selectmode` contains `mouse`:

```
set selectmode+=mouse
```

Then Vim enter in select mode if you select an area using the mouse.

If `selectmode` contains `cmd`:

```
set selectmode=+cmd
```

Then Vim enter in select mode when you hit `v`, `V` or <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd>
More information with `:help 'selectmode'`

If `selectmode` contains `key` and `keymodel` is `startsel,endsel` then Vim enter in Select mode when you hit a shifted cursor motion (e.g. <kbd>Shift Left</kbd>, <kbd>Shift Up</kbd>, <kbd>Shift Right</kbd>, <kbd>Shift Down</kbd>, <kbd>Shift Home</kbd>, <kbd>Shift End</kbd>, ...) and quit Select mode when you hit any other key.

Remark: You can set these two options using the `:behave mswin` command.

Remark:

- You can switch from Select mode to Visual mode and back using <kbd>Ctrl g</kbd>
- You can switch to normal mode for one action with <kbd>Ctrl o</kbd> (like in Insert mode)

## Solution

For your problem having two mappings depending on the mode is probably not the solution.

But you can detect the mode you are in using the `mode()` function and do your mapping the following way:

```
vnoremap <expr> <A-b> mode()==#'V' ? "<ESC>'<I**<ESC>'>A**<ESC>gv" : "o<ESC>i**<ESC>gvO<ESC>2la**<ESC>gv4l"
```

Comment: I think you can also toggle select mode from visual mode with C-g or something. This answer could also point to the list of modes and the explanations of Visual and Select modes in the help (and maybe explain the differences in Visual and Select mode with more than how to trigger them).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have enriched the select mode paragraph :-)